# Cannot delete a version - gcloud app versions stop [id]

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I cannot use the "gcloud app versions stop", I dont know how to quit automatic mode.

It throws the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.versions.stop) INVALID_ARGUMENT: serving status cannot be changed for Automatic Scaling versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/stop):

> This command stops serving the specified versions. It may only be used
>   if the scaling module for your service has been set to manual.

The scaling pattern for your app is defined in the [app.yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements) (or appengine-web.xml file in Java), for example:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 5
```

Note that if you haven't specified scaling policy in that file, it defaults to automatic scaling, thus the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get into a situation where you're getting the error you mentioned, but can't change the yaml file as mentioned in [LundinCast's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52347040/1024735) because you're also getting this error when you try to deploy:

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: Your app may not have more than 15 versions. Please delete one of the existing versions before trying to create a new version.

In that situation, I wasn't able to find a solution from the terminal, but it's easy enough to go to the "versions" page of the console to manually delete a version, which is available here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions